# How do I re-use the book's text for different document formats?

Tags: formatting

Any ideas how I could re-use the book's text that I have written (it's in `chapter1.tex`, `chapter2.tex`, etc.) in various document formats (a4, letter, mobile device format, etc). The problem I am facing is that I have placed various `\newpage`s in the chapters so they looked ok for `a4` format. But now when I tried to compile the book for `letter` those `\newpage`s are in the wrong places, so I have to have a different copy of text with `\newpage`s in the right places. What's the general strategy for re-using the text for various formats?

The reason why I am using `\newpage` throughout my book is that `\section`s sometimes appear at the bottom of the page, and I want to force them into the new page, so I use `\newpage` just before that `\section` that was at the bottom of current page.

Here is a screenshot example:

[image]

See how `4.12` is at very bottom and the code example is cut in half? That's why I insert these `\newpage`s to force it on a new page so it looked ok!

I am using `memoir` document class and the code boxes are done via `\begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}`.

Comment: @Peteris I doubt that using `\newline` makes something better; I dare say it makes it worse. Do you mean `\linebreak`, of course, don't you? `;-)`

Comment: One of the strategies: don't put commands to force manual formatting.

Comment: Page 19 of [l2short](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) clearly states that `\newline` and `\linebreak` should only be used in "special cases". If you haven't read this introduction, make up for it.

Comment: @Peteris `\newpage` is just the same as `\newline` (there's `\pagebreak`). You have the text, copy into a new file, delete all such formatting commands and, if necessary put others.

Answer (score 6):

Even though you seem to have abandoned this question, I am going to answer it. The reason is this: No matter how generic you make your code, you will eventually have to input manual layout tweaks here and there. This should be done sparingly, and as a last resort, but in any manuscript of a given size and complexity, I think it is inevitable that you will need to do so.
Now the problem is one of making your tweaks appear conditionally, depending on paper size and possibly other layout parameters.
Here is one way to do this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\makeatletter
\def\setlayout#1{\@setlayout#1,\relax,}
\def\@setlayout#1,{\ifx\relax#1\else
  \expandafter\def\csname layout@#1\endcsname{}%
  \expandafter\@setlayout\fi}
\def\layout #1#{\@layout #1,\relax,}
\def\@layout#1,{\ifx\relax#1\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else
\ifcsname layout@#1\endcsname
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\layout@yes\else
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@layout
\fi
  \fi}
\def\layout@yes#1#{\@firstoftwo}
\makeatother

% demo
\setlayout{one,two}
\begin{document}
\layout one,four{\message{[the first]}}{\message{[not the first]}}
\layout five,two{\message{[the second]}}{\message{[not the second]}}
\layout six,three{\message{[the third]}}{\message{[not the third]}}
\end{document}
```

In a real document, you might set, say options a5 and booklet using

```
\setlayout{a5,booklet}
```

and then, whenever a particular layout tweak (say, a `\newpage`) has to be done only for the a5 case or the screen case, you write

```
\layout a5,screen{\newpage}{}
```

The second parameter is there in case you need to do something else in the other cases.