# How do I prevent LaTeX from putting \sections at the very end of the page?

Tags: sectioning, listings, page-breaking, sections-paragraphs

Please take a look at the screenshot below. I am having a problem where LaTeX would put the `\section` at the very end of the page. So far I fixed it by using `\newpage` but [I just learned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19812/how-do-i-re-use-the-books-text-for-different-document-formats) that it was totally wrong.

I am using `memoir` document class together with `listings` package for code examples. The page in the screenshot was generated this way:

```
\section{Substitute (find and replace) "foo" with "bar" on each line}

\begin{lstlisting}
awk '{ sub(/foo/,"bar"); print }'
\end{lstlisting}

....

\section{Substitute "foo" with "bar" only on lines that contain "baz"}

\begin{lstlisting}
awk '/baz/ { gsub(/foo/, "bar") }; { print }'
\end{lstlisting}

...
```

Anyone knows how to make `\section`s always go on a new page if they are at very bottom?

[image]

Comment: I think  you need a package `needspace`.

Comment: Somehow the `lstlisting` environment annuls the LaTeX mechanism that prevents page breaks after a `\section` command.

Answer (score 4):

> `needspace` package provides the \needspace and \Needspace
>   macros for requesting a certain amount
>   of space on the current page for the
>   following materia.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=single}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]    
\Needspace*{10\baselineskip}% you need a vertical space of 10 times \baselineskip for the following section.
\section{Something}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        hello world !
        hello universe !
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes. Adjust the `...` in `\Needspace*{...\textheight}`. You might use `0.3` for 1/3 of paper height.

Comment: The problem with this "solution" is that the "certain amount of space" needs to be set individually for every `lstlisting` environment and that it is easy to make wrong guesses about the amount of space actually needed. (In your example, `\Needspace*{7\baselineskip}` would have been sufficient, as you can easily test by setting `\textheight 610pt` in the preamble.

Comment: Manual adjustment per section should be done at the final release of your book.

Comment: @Peteris: The "certain amount of space" is essentially the space needed for a `\section` command plus the space needed for the particular `lstlisting` environment. Problems would arise if the paper size were so small that `\section` commands would produce line breaks.